# Print character in a floating numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np
from random import random
x = np.array( [random() , random(), random()])
label = np.array("Ar")
y = np.hstack((label,x))
print(y)
```

I want to add a label in front of a 3-D numpy array but it will not return a floating number

```
['Ar' '0.' '0.' '0.']
```

Can I overwrite the array to store floating number?

Comment: You mentioned 3D array but your example is a 1D array. Do you want a label as first column of each row or a label for an entire ND array?

Comment: How do you plan to use this label? It looks like you are looking for a key-value structure, which is a dictionnary: ```{'foo': np.random.rand(3)}```

Comment: I have a bunch of 1d array and have to do some operation on x before printing them.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing here i, that numpy arrays only support a single type per array. When you create the array `y` by stacking a 1D array of floats (your array `x`) and a 0D array of type `'<U2'` meaning two unicode characters (`your array label`) numpy has to settle on a single data type. In your case this is `'<U32'` or 32 unicode characters.

Looking at your code in ipython shows this:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: from random import random

In [3]: x = np.array( [random() , random(), random()])

In [4]: x
Out[4]: array([ 0.63426736,  0.79011426,  0.66686608])

In [5]: label = np.array("Ar")

In [6]: label
Out[6]: 
array('Ar', 
      dtype='<U2')

In [7]: y = np.hstack((label,x))

In [8]: y
Out[8]: 
array(['Ar', '0.6342673585559033', '0.7901142593791942',
       '0.6668660767693766'], 
      dtype='<U32')
```

So by adding the label you implicitly converted the floats in `x` to unicode strings.

To avoid this you could manage the label and the array separately. For example you could create a tuple of the two items like this:

```
In [9]: label = "Ar"

In [10]: x = np.random.random(3)

In [11]: ar = (label, x)

In [12]: ar
Out[12]: ('Ar', array([ 0.65850863,  0.89673635,  0.11127903]))

In [13]: ar[1].dtype
Out[13]: dtype('float64')
```

I hope this helps.